# Chromebook/ChromeOS stats on Google Play developer console

Tags: android, google-play, analytics, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Google has steadily been introducing Android apps and Play store to ChromeOS, with the announcement today that [all Chromebooks will run Android apps](http://uk.businessinsider.com/google-chromebook-android-apps-chrome-os-support-list-2017-1). Is there any way Android developers can access data about usage on these devices, via the Play console?